# Problem about absolute value

Tags: absolute-value

> $$\begin{align*}
> |x|=x &\text{if }x\geq 0\\
> |x|=-x &\text{if }x\lt 0.
> \end{align*}$$
>   Show that $|xy|=|x||y|$.

I try to prove it as follows:

$|xy|=xy$ if $xy\geq 0$, 
but $xy\geq 0$ if and only if $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$.
Since $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$, then 
$x=|x|$ and $y=|y|$
hence from $|xy|=xy$
we have $|xy|=|x||y|$.

Am I correct?

How can I  show  the following two cases?

i. Show that $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$.

ii. If $y\gt 0$ and $-y\leq x \leq y$, then $|x|\lt y$

Comment: Please make your title more descriptive and finish your question.

Comment: That is a rather bad, undescriptive title for your question, don't you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, you are not correct. It is false that $xy\geq 0$ if and only if $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$. For example, if $x=-1$ and $y=-1$, then $x\lt 0$, $y\lt 0$, and $xy = (-1)(-1) = 1\geq 0$. So your claim is incorrect, and thus your argument is incorrect. There are other possibilities, and you need to consider them too.
2. Even *if* your argument were correct for that part, you would not be done yet. You only considered the case in which $xy\geq 0$. What if $xy\lt 0$? You also need to do that case.
3. The last statement is incorrect. For example, if $x=y$, then $-y\leq x\leq y$ is true, but $|x|\lt y$ is false.
4. To show (i), consider the different cases. What happens if $x$ and $y$ are both positive? If $x$ and $y$ are both negative? If $x$ is positive and $y$ negative and $x+y\geq 0$? If $x$ is positive, $y$ is negative, and $x+y\lt 0$? If $x$ is negative and $y$ positive?
5. To show (a corrected version of) (ii), consider the cases. What happens if $0\leq x\leq y$? What happens if $-y\lt x\lt 0$?